# Reading from socket to basic_filebuf

Tags: c++, sockets, client

It's code from client part  (using )

```
   struct sockaddr_in stSockAddr;
   int Res;
   int SocketFD;
   SocketFD = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
   if (-1 == SocketFD)
   {
      perror("cannot create socket");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

    memset(&stSockAddr, 0, sizeof(stSockAddr));

    stSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    stSockAddr.sin_port = htons(8182);
    Res = inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &stSockAddr.sin_addr);
```

And I get responce from server using

```
   char buffer[4096] = "";
   n = read(aSocketFD, buffer, 4096);
```

My questin is:
Can I get responce like **std::basic_filebuf**? Or can I get responce to FILE *? 
Socket is a file handler, so I can do it, but how?

Comment: I don't really have a fix to your actual problem, but it might be worth checking out a networking library such as boost.asio.

Comment: You might be able to get a `FILE` pointer by using [`fdopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen), and I think I seen someone doing socket "iostreams" but I can't remember where I saw that. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **C code**, you can use a descriptor like FILE* calling fdopen(): associates a stream with a file descriptor (POSIX.1 standard).

Comment: This was helpful. FILE * _fd = fdopen(aSocketFD, "r+");   std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > streamIn(_fd);

Answer (score 0):

If you asked this because you want good performance:

On linux you can use `sendfile`, this works with simple file descriptors (fd):

```
ssize_t sendfile(int out_fd, int in_fd, off_t *offset, size_t count);
```

Some other unix systems also support this API call, but it's not part of POSIX, so it's not portable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to subclass `std::streambuf` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes, I can use std::basic_streambuf. But I need std::basic_filebuf

Comment: @user1143825 While a socket descriptor can be used by file-handling functions like `read`, `write` and `close`, it is **not** a file. Therefore you should not be using e.g. `std::basic_filebuf` but inherit directly from `std::basic_streambuf`. One obvious reason is that you don't need support for seeking since it won't work on sockets.